# How can I check if a string contains in a file in C?

Tags: c, file

Im trying to find a string in a file in C. How can I do that?

Declared as:

```
      C_paciente *inicio_cadastro_paciente;
```

I tried:

```
int found = 0;
  while (read(inicio_cadastro_paciente, sizeof(C_paciente), 1, arq_paciente) == 1)
   {
          if (strcmp(name, (*inicio_cadastro_paciente) -> name) == 0)

     { 
   found = 1;  // we found it
   break;      // stop looking
 }
 }
  if (found) {
   printf("Name found!");
   return 1;
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string is in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278294/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-in-a-file).

Comment: No.Its not duplicated question. I tried that one but it didnt work.

Comment: Perhaps I missed something, but the first answer in the cited duplicated is an answer to "Im trying to find a string in a file in C. How can I do that?". How did it not work?

Comment: `while(!feof(fp)){...}` is always wrong.

Comment: @jww the other question has a similar title, but the actual question is about finding strings within lines of text in a file. This question is about finding strings in structured data; using `fgets()` as in the cited answer will fail.

Comment: @Paul - this question does not state that. He/she clearly asks how to find a string in a file. If that's not the case, then the question needs to be changed. We can't be expected to answer questions that were not asked.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What type is `C_paciente *inicio_cadastro_paciente`? You say `struct`, but you do not `read` a `struct`. Please show the `struct` declaration and how `name` and `inicio_cadastro_paciente-> name` are filled/assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't scan into `&name`, just use `name` - it's already a `char *`:

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

Don't rely on `feof` to tell you whether you found a match. It will be true if you match on the very last item in the file.

Add something like:

```
int found = 0;
```

Assuming `C_paciente.name` is a regular, 0-terminated C string:

```
while (read(&inicio_cadastro_paciente, sizeof(C_paciente), 1, arq_paciente) == 1)
{
  if (strcmp(name, inicio_cadastro_paciente.name) == 0)
  { 
    found = 1;  // we found it
    break;      // stop looking
  }
}

if (found) {
  printf("Name found!");
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: It still not working ): . I forgot to say that, the inicio_cadastro_paciente is a pointer.

Comment: Then use `inicio_cadastro_paciente` instead of `&inicio_cadastro_paciente`. And make sure it's been initialized, and points somewhere. Otherwise, without sample data, or enough code to reproduce the problem, there's not much we can do.

Comment: Ok. I wrote that, but it still not working. I will edit my question to you, for u see what is wrong.

Comment: this answer only finds a string if the search string matches the whole line from the file.  suggest using strstr() rather than strcmp()

Comment: Thanks anyway. I gonna try to find anotherway to do that.